# how to go back (move back) to a form with a value

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am facing a serious issue with a lookup window, Please help to solve this.

see the steps of my form opens

1. Opens first form (from Dashboard)

   ```
   Dim ObjOrder As New OrderFormFrm
   ObjOrder.USER = USER
   ObjOrder.Show()
   ```
2. Next I have to open a popwindow based on a textbox event.

   ```
   Private Sub txtCustCode_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles txtCustCode.MouseClick 

       Dim PopUpCustomer As New searchCustomerfrm
       PopUpCustomer.ShowDialog()
   End Sub
   ```
3. I have to goback to Orderform with a value based on a gridview row click event

   ```
   Private Sub DGVCustomer_CellContentDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGVCustomer.CellContentDoubleClick

       OrderFormFrm.txtCustCode.Text = Val(DGVCustomer.Item(1, e.RowIndex).Value)`

       Me.Close()

   End Sub
   ```

The problems is, I am getting value to Orderform's textbox when I start project form from `'OrderFormFrm'` (project properties setting-start form), and not getting if I started project from the dashboard.

I need to display the value `'DGVCustomer.Item(1, e.RowIndex).Value'` in Order forms text box `'txtCustCode'`

Please help to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could make a shared function on the `searchCustomerfrm` form that returns the value that you expect from the form:

```
Public Shared Function GetCustomer()
      Dim PopUpCustomer As New searchCustomerfrm
      If PopUpCustomer.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
           Return Val(PopUpCustomer.DGVCustomer.Item(1, PopUpCustomer.DGVCustomer.CurrentRow.Index).Value) 
      Else
           Return Nothing
      End If
End Function
```

On the `DGVCustomer_CellContentDoubleClick` write this:

```
Private Sub DGVCustomer_CellContentDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGVCustomer.CellContentDoubleClick 

    Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK

End Sub
```

To call the `searchCustomerfrm` from `OrderFormFrm` you'll have this code:

`txtCustCode.Text = searchCustomerfrm.GetCustomer`

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but getting an error. How to get rowIndex in this function GetCustomer ?  e not declared

Comment: Error 1: 'e' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level, Error 2: Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class.

Comment: Sorry I missed a few things on the value to return, I've changed the code it should work fine!

Comment: Thank you friend..brilliant idea, it is working fine, you saved my day, Thank you very much for your all kind support

Answer (score 0):

Unless I missed something, you need to be calling the original form by instance name and not by type...

```
Private Sub DGVCustomer_CellContentDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGVCustomer.CellContentDoubleClick

    ObjOrder.txtCustCode.Text = Val(DGVCustomer.Item(1, e.RowIndex).Value)

Me.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: but problem not solved yet, How getCustomer function returns this -Val(DGVCustomer.Item(1, e.RowIndex).Value) ?

Comment: Sorry, as per first suggested answer I got the getCutomer.

Comment: Is your dgv on the PopUpForm?

Comment: I am getting result as per my code given above when I start my project form from OrderFormFrm (in project properties setup). If I changed project to start from dashboard, its not working..

Comment: Thanks all for yours support.. i got solution

Answer (score 0):

add a public property called sendingForm to your searchCustomerFrm class

```
Public Class searchCustomerFrm
Public sendingForm As OrderFormFrm
```

Then set that property to the sending form when you create the new form

```
Private Sub txtCustCode_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles txtCustCode.MouseClick 

    Dim PopUpCustomer As New searchCustomerfrm
    PopUpCustomer.sendingForm = Me
    PopUpCustomer.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

Finally, set the textbox property of the sending form

```
Private Sub DGVCustomer_CellContentDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGVCustomer.CellContentDoubleClick


        sendingForm.txtCustCode.Text = Val(dgvCustomer.Item(1, e.RowIndex).Value)

        Me.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: As long as that works for you, I would look at using a private property for the sending form instead.  I just wanted to have you try this first.